# Delete where TimeStamp is minimum in table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want delete rows in my table where I have minimum Time stamp value.

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `time_Stamp` =MIN(`table_name.time_Stamp`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE time_Stamp =(select MIN(a.time_Stamp) from table_name a)
```

Comment: DELETE FROM `restaurants` WHERE `created_on` =(select MIN(`restaurants.created_on`) from `restaurants`)

it give error as "You can't specify target table 'restaurants' for update in FROM clause "

Comment: try with values and if not works then show me error or if it's right then mark my answer as right

Comment: i am able to solve it by limit
eg:


DELETE FROM users ORDER BY created_on ASC LIMIT 1;

Comment: delete query syntax not allowed order by. It is simple logic. You are delete data then why are you use 'order by'.

Answer (score 0):

First you do a select statement like

```
select * FROM table_name WHERE time_Stamp =(select MIN(table_name.time_Stamp) from table_name)
```

and check whether you are getting all the correct records then you can use

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE time_Stamp =(select MIN(table_name.time_Stamp) from table_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DELETE x 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(a) min_a FROM my_table ) y 
    ON y.min_a = x.a;
```